# Python SQLalchemy Join lookup by User

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Wrapping my head around a way to get a list of Jobs associated to a User. My DB Model goes a little something like this.

```
class Job(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # Relationship Rows
    actions = db.relationship('JobAction', backref='job')


class JobAction(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # Linked Rows
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))

    # Relationship Rows
    user = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys=[user_id], backref='jobactions')
```

I need to get a list of Jobs that are associated to a User. I can use either the `User` already matching a logged in users details. Or the `user.id`.

I was looking at something like the below, but no dice. I can see it's overly optimistic a query, but can't see what's up. Potentially a missing Join.

```
# Get User first.
user = User.query.filter_by(id=1).first()

# Get their Jobs
jobs = Job.query.filter_by(actions.user=user).all()
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are missing a foreign key. If your database model looked like this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    jobactions = db.relationship("JobAction", back_populates="user")

class Job(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'jobs'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    jobactions = db.relationship('JobAction', backref='job')

class JobAction(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'jobactions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    job_id =  db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('jobs.id'))
    user = db.relationship(User, back_populates="jobactions")
    job =  db.relationship(Job, back_populates="jobactions")
```

Then you could use:

```
jobs = [ jobaction.job for jobaction in user.jobactions ]
```